# Best approach to detect a nonexistent URL

Tags: ios, dns

I'd like some advice on how to detect a "bad" URL before issuing an NSURLConnection call.  By bad, I mean a non-existent host (e.g., www.no_such_host.com).  I would need to first parse the URL to get just the host (suggestions welcome!) and then would like to see if the host actually is registered.

Is there a simple approach to using the DNS Resolver lookup, available in the iOS libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you, I would just go with the connection, then just catch in `NSURLConnectionDelegate`'s `– connection:didFailWithError:` method the error. `NSURLConnection` will still go to resolve the URL that you enter. The errors that `NSURLConnection` will throw can be found in the [Foundation Constants Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html) (look for `NSURLErrorDomain`). If I remember correctly, the error that will be thrown is `NSURLErrorCannotFindHost`.

Comment: yes, just try to make the connection, and if it fails look at what the error was. No need to try to determine URL validity ahead of time...